# How do I add class javadoc in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I am using Intellij IDEA.

I know how to work "fix doc commnet"
It's always using method.

My question~
I would like to add javadoc on Class.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special, just place the cursor above the class and type:

```
/**
```

and press enter.

Comment: I have founded solution that i use live template.

I made a template code and then type "javadoc_class" It makes javadoc class type

Comment: '/**
 * Project : $PROJECT$
 * Date : $DATE$
 * Author : $USER$
 * Description : $DESC$
 */
$END$'

Comment: Removed an extra star (*) otherwise it will appear in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Before each class you want documentation for, insert `/**` and press enter. A javadoc block should be generated for you. If you want to go ahead and generate the javadoc, do `Tools -> Generate Javadoc` and add whatever configuration options you feel necessary.